# Embedded Google videos do not show in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, safari

I am trying to watch older videos (from Google Videos days) in my browser, like: http://www.charlierose.com/view/interview/3377

I'm using Mac OS X. The video "Play" button appears in Safari, Firefox and Chrome but when I press Play it doesn't work in either of these three browser. Instead, I get a screen with the Google Videos button that is unresponsive, see below:
[image]

How can these be played on Mac OS X? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with OS X or any specific browser. The video simply doesn't exist anymore.

If you check the browser console, you can see details of that error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://video.google.com/videofeed?fgvns=1&fai=1&docid=-5987651708538113616&begin=4000&len=1563000&hl=undefined`